# Referencing XAML element from C# with x:Name

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

I'm developing an android app with Xamarin and C#

in the file foo.xaml (the XAML file) I have something like this:

```
<Image x:Name="pippo"/>
```

in the file foo.xaml.cs (the C# file) I tried to reference the element in this way:

```
Image im = (Image)pippo;
```

I was sure that I'd get it right cause pippo's an image in the xaml file, but unfortunatly it gives an System.InvalidCastException.

Why is that?

Comment: Is this Xamarin.Forms?  You should not need to cast it.  I would verify that both classes are the same, and not two different classes both named Image from different namespaces.

Comment: I am unsure why you are trying this . You can use  'pippo' directly for your use .

Comment: Yes your right. I can using directly pippo without any cast...

Comment: but it keeps giving me an invalid cast exception